# Resolving SRV Records in Java using xbill. Correct Query string?

Tags: java, dns, port, lookup, srv

I am trying to obtain SRV records using org.xbill.DNS in java for my domain

I have the following setup on my domain (eg: example.com) at the moment:

Record:

```
HostName:         ramuh
IP Address/URL:   1.1.1.1   // the public ip of my computer
Record Type:      A (Address)
```

And I created the following SRV Record:

```
_SERVICE  :        _rdp
_PROTOCOL :        _tcp
PRIORITIY :        1
WEIGHT    :        1
PORT      :        5000      
TARGET    :        ramuh.example.com
```

The query String i am using:

```
_rdp._tcp.ramuh.example.com
```

I would like to be able to get the SRV Record for ramuh.example.com

so i can build:

ramuh.example.com:5000 (that then is translated automatically to 1.1.1.1:5000, not from my side)

Currently using this code (s is the inputted domain for which a list of SRV records needs to be returned):

```
    String s = "ramuh.example.com";  // the inputted string, I need to obtain the Port to be added to this
    ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
    String query = "_rdp._tcp." + s;
    try{
        Record[] records = new Lookup(query,Type.SRV).run();  // returning null
        if(records!= null && records.length>0) {
            for(Record r : records){
                SRVRecord srv = (SRVRecord)r;
                String hostname = srv.getTarget().toString().replaceFirst("\\.$","");
                int port = srv.getPort();
                ret.add(hostname+":"+port);
            }
            return ret;
        }
        else{
           return null;
        }
    }catch(TextParseException e){
        return null;
    }
```

new Lookup() is returning null so i would assume that the query string being passed is invalid. What changes do i need to carry out on the Query String or SRV Record for this to work?

Using namecheap as a domain.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query does not have to match the target in the SRV record but rather the domain you are using

so the query would be  `_rdp._tcp.example.com`

This can be verified by testing on [MXToolbox's SRV lookup](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=srv:_rdp._tcp.mangusbrother.com&run=toolpage#) however will not work using org.xbill.DSN.Lookup.

The issue with Lookup has been simplified into another question: [23935847](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935847/lookup-srv-org-xbill-not-finding-records)